# JS - merge object same array lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to transform a array of multiple object in one array object, 
I explain myself, I wish to group for each table the objects that carry the same "month" and replace the properties that have the same value by adding their ID at the beginning:
ex:
quantity: 1
becomes fpsIssuedQuantity (in camelCase). http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/96589/

here are my data :

```js
var data = {
 "2018-01": [
  { id:"fpsIssued", month:"2018-01", quantity:"28" }, 
  { id:"dgfipIncome", month:"2018-01", amount:1350 }, 
  { id:"antaiPaidFps", month:"2018-01", quantity:2242 }
 ], 

 "2018-02": [
  { id: "fpsIssued", month: "2018-02",  quantity: "29" }, 
  { id: "dgfipIncome", month: "2018-02", amount: 8530 }, 
  { id: "antaiPaidFps", month: "2018-02", quantity: 4857}
 ]
};

console.log(data);
```

and the expected data :

```js
var expectedData = {
  "2018-01": [
      { month: "2018-01", fpsIssuedquantity: "28", 
      dgfipIncomeamount: 1350, antaiPaidFpsQuantity: 2242 
      }
 ], 
  "2018-02": [
    { month: "2018-02", fpsIssuedquantity: "29", 
    dgfipIncomeamount: 8530, antaiPaidFpsQuantity: 4857
    }
 ]
};

console.log(expectedData);
```

i use lodash and angularjs but i can not get my result .. please could you help me?

Comment: does it has a special reason to use `quantity` **and** `amount`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the data that my webService returns to me : quantity is a number of element and amount is the amount of all element in $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map new objects with wanted new property names and values in new objects.

```js
var data = { "2018-01": [{ id: "fpsIssued", month: "2018-01", quantity: "28" }, { id: "dgfipIncome", month: "2018-01", amount: 1350 }, { id: "antaiPaidFps", month: "2018-01", quantity: 2242 }], "2018-02": [{ id: "fpsIssued", month: "2018-02", quantity: "29" }, { id: "dgfipIncome", month: "2018-02", amount: 8530 }, { id: "antaiPaidFps", month: "2018-02", quantity: 4857 }] },
    result = Object.assign(
        ...Object
            .entries(data)
            .map(
                ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: Object.assign(...v.map(o => ({ month: o.month, [o.id + ('quantity' in o ? 'Quantity' : 'Amount')]: 'quantity' in o ? o.quantity : o.amount }))) })
            )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```